# reporting services expression avoid comma if the field value is null

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have the following expression and displays the comma after each column. I do not want show the comma(,) after each field value, if the field value is null. I would appreciate any help. thank you.

```
=Fields!address.Value &", "&Fields!city.Value &", "& Trim(Fields!zipcode.Value) &", "& Fields!state_code.Value
```

Comment: In T-SQL it would be `COALESCE(address + ',', '') + COALESCE(city + ',', '')` - have you considered implementing your reports as stored procedures instead of this hokey VB/SQL hybrid in the report builder?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I did change my stored procedure to use your suggestion. It works now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stored procedure. Then you can say:

```
SELECT COALESCE(address + ',', '') + COALESCE(city + ',', '') + ...
```